# Degenerate perturbation theory: typo in Sakurai: Eq. 5.2.15

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, textbook-erratum

**Book:** Modern Quantum Mechanics (Revised edition): J J Sakurai

In the equation 5.2.15 on the RHS, should the symbol $\epsilon$ be replaced with the 'not an element of' symbol?

Comment: -1. If you're going to immediately answer your own question, at least do it *well*. Give the equation with the typo in it in your question, explain why it is wrong, and correct it.

Comment: If anyone wants a full list of errors, written by the author, instead of just this question, please go to http://fisica.ufpr.br/bettega/ErrataMQM.pdf

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo. The symbol $\epsilon$ should be replaced with the 'not an element of' symbol.

Comment: Posting an answer that is practically identical to your own question is mind-numbingly pointless.

Comment: @StephenG A question and an answer are fundamentally different objects. I don't understand how do they seem identical to you.

Comment: And there's also the very strange use of "**You** are right" in your own reply to your own non-question.  Are you twins ?